# Custom Role was deleted and I cannot undelete it using gcloud command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I was trying to apply IAM permissions in one project and `terraform` managed to detect changes in GCP that were done outside of terraform. Change list consisted of deleted custom roles that were previously created by terraform. In plan, terraform showed that it wanted to recreate those custom roles. I tried to apply but I got error

```
Error: Error creating the custom project role projects/project-id/roles/gcsManageNotifications: googleapi: Error 400: You can't create a role_id (gcsManageNotifications) which has been marked for deletion., failedPrecondition
```

I tried to debug this and do same using `gcloud` command but effect was the same.

```bash
$ gcloud iam roles create cdnInvalidateCache --permissions=compute.urlMaps.get,compute.urlMaps.invalidateCache --project=project-id
Note: permissions [compute.urlMaps.get, compute.urlMaps.invalidateCache] are in 'TESTING' stage which means the functionality is not mature and they can go away in the future. This can break your workflows, so do not use them in production systems!

Are you sure you want to make this change? (Y/n)?  y

ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.create) FAILED_PRECONDITION: You can't create a role_id (cdnInvalidateCache) which has been marked for deletion.
```

```bash
$ gcloud iam roles undelete cdnInvalidateCache --project project-id                                                                
ERROR: (gcloud.iam.roles.undelete) NOT_FOUND: The role named projects/project-id/roles/cdnInvalidateCache was not found.
```

```bash
$ gcloud iam roles list --project project-id --show-deleted                                                                        
Listed 0 items.
```

Am I doing something wrong or is it some bug in GCP?

I'm pretty sure I did not delete any custom role in this project. Also my terraform config apply same custom roles to multiple projects and somehow just this one project was affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reason for failure of “undelete custom role”**:

To do **operations** (create and manage) on a **project level custom role** you must have the permission `Role Administrator (roles/iam.roleAdmin)` and it looks like you already have that permission.Also as per your comment you did not delete any custom roles in this project but there are chances that someone who has similar permissions might have deleted the [custom roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#deleting-custom-role) and it might already have crossed **7 days of grace period** and that's the reason you are unable to **undelete/recover** the role.

**Custom role Deletion:**

As per the public [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#deleting-custom-role), the permanent **deletion process** takes **30 days**. During the 30-day window, the role and all associated bindings are permanently removed, and you cannot create a new role with the same role ID and once the role has been permanently deleted, up to **44 days** after the initial deletion request, you can create a new role using the same role ID.

**Custom role Undeletion:**

You can **un-delete** a role and return it to its previous state by following the steps mentioned in [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-custom-roles#undeleting_a_custom_role).Note that, Roles can only be undeleted within 7 days. After **7 days**, the role can be permanently deleted at any time, and all role bindings that refer to the role are removed.

**Update** :

You can refer to the [Caller identities in audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#user-id) to check the logs accordingly.

Audit logs record the identity that performed the logged operations on the Google Cloud resource and it is available in the `AuthenticationInfo` field of [AuditLog](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit/api/ref/rest/Shared.Types/AuditLog) objects. Similarly, IP address of the caller is held in the `RequestMetadata.caller_ip` field.

Run the following command to read your Google Cloud project-level audit log entries.

```
gcloud logging read "logName : projects/project_id/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com" \
    --project=project_id
```

Add the **--freshness** flag to your command to read logs that are more than 1 day old.

For more information you can refer to the [available audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/audit-logging#available-logs) documentation.

Comment: Can I somehow check who exactly deleted custom role?

Comment: @piotrekkr , I have updated the answer and included the audit logs information.